# Missing keyword error in Oracle anonymous PL/SQL block

Tags: oracle, plsql

An anonymous PL/SQL block:

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR employees_in_10_cur
    IS
    SELECT *
    FROM ad_week_table

BEGIN
  FOR employee_rec 
  IN employees_in_10_cur
  LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(employee_rec.ad_no || ',' || employee_rec.week_no);
  END LOOP;
END;
```

I get a missing keyword error when I execute this block. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it too localized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put a semi-colon after defining cursor query;

```
DECLARE
       CURSOR employees_in_10_cur
       IS
          SELECT *
            FROM ad_week_table;

    BEGIN
       FOR employee_rec 
       IN employees_in_10_cur
       LOOP
          DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
             employee_rec.ad_no || ',' || employee_rec.week_no );
       END LOOP;
    END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a semi-colon at the end of your cursor:

```
CURSOR employees_in_10_cur
   IS
      SELECT *
        FROM ad_week_table;
```

The error message will always give you the line number of the error occurring. Please always check this and look in that area.

For instance; if I change the table so I can run this I get the following:

```
SQL> declare
  2
  3     cursor employees_in_10_cur is
  4      select *
  5        from user_tables
  6
  7  begin
  8     for employee_rec in employees_in_10_cur loop
  9        dbms_output.put_line (
 10           employee_rec.ad_no || ',' || employee_rec.week_no );
 11     end loop;
 12  end;
 13  /
   for employee_rec in employees_in_10_cur loop
       *
ERROR at line 8:
ORA-06550: line 8, column 8:
PL/SQL: ORA-00905: missing keyword
ORA-06550: line 4, column 5:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 11, column 4:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of the following:
begin function pragma procedure subtype type <an identifier>
<a double-quoted delimited-identifier> current cursor delete
exists prior
```

You have 3 errors; one at line 8 because the cursor is invalid, one at line 11 because the loop doesn't happen because the cursor is invalid and one at line 4, which says "statement ignored".